# Boost Linking problems

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have tried to link boost in my CMakeList file by

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /user/software/boost/boost-1.69-x86_64-cc7/include)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /user/software/boost/boost-1.69-x86_64-cc7/lib)
find_package(Boost 1.54 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem program_options system)
```

and i get the following warning when doing cmake

```
CMake Warning at /user/software/cmake/cmake-3.7.1-x86_64-cc7/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):

Imported targets not available for Boost version 106900
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /user/software/cmake/cmake-3.7.1-x86_64-cc7/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /user/software/cmake/cmake-3.7.1-x86_64-cc7/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  util/src/CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package)
```

So when i do the make command i get the error

```
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, char>::name() const':
checkFile.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EEcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EEcE4nameEv]+0x25): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg[abi:cxx11]'
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
checkFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0x112): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
checkFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0x187): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)'
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o: In function `main':
checkFile.cpp:(.text.startup+0x63): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
checkFile.cpp:(.text.startup+0x222): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o: In function `void boost::program_options::validate<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*, int) [clone .constprop.475]':
checkFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINS3_IT0_S4_ISB_ESaISB_EEESaISE_EEPSA_IT_SaISJ_EEi.constprop.475[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EEcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSA_]+0xc9): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, int)'
checkFile.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINS3_IT0_S4_ISB_ESaISB_EEESaISE_EEPSA_IT_SaISJ_EEi.constprop.475[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EEcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSA_]+0x4b4): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN5boost10wrapexceptINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE0_NS_16exception_detail10clone_implINS4_19error_info_injectorIS2_EEEE[_ZTVN5boost10wrapexceptINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost10wrapexceptINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost10wrapexceptINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE]+0x30): more undefined references to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const' follow
CMakeFiles/checkFile.dir/checkFile.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EEcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EEcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) const'
```

Any help please would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compiling your code while defining macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, e.g.:

```
add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

> If you get linker errors about undefined references to symbols that involve types in the `std::__cxx11` namespace or the tag `[abi:cxx11]` then it probably indicates that you are trying to link together object files that were compiled with different values for the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` macro. This commonly happens when linking to a third-party library that was compiled with an older version of GCC. If the third-party library cannot be rebuilt with the new ABI then you will need to recompile your code with the old ABI.

Comment: Indeed, if it's a system boost, that's probably the reason.

Comment: sorry im new to this, how to i compile the code with this macro

Comment: @AndrewGroves Added a CMake line for you.